# How to fix "Type mismatch" error in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, type-mismatch

I Created a Login Form in access, with two TextBox; one for UserName and the other one for Password. both have a number format. I made a command that shows a textbox with the message "insert User ID and your Password" when both textBoxes are empty.

But today I see the error "Type mismatch" (Run-Time error '13')

```vb
If IsNull(Me.txtUserId Or Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "insert User ID and your Password", vbInformation, "Caution"
    Me.txtUserId.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsNull` doesn't work with logic like that. Try with:

```
If IsNull(Me.txtUserId + Me.txtPassword) Then
```

or:

```
If IsNull(Me.txtUserId) Or IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
```